# Pivot or Panorama for my WP7 books app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have to build a library Windows Phone 7 app to list books by author, editor, period.
I've not clear if it's better to use Panorama or Pivot control: i've seen that both would be good so i don't really understand the best component to use.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Most definitively Pivot. Don't use a Panorama for displaying data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A panorama control is great for showing a summary or a few top items you want to display in your app in a visually pleasing manner, but isn't suitable for showing large quantities of data.

A pivot is good for switching between categories such those you mention (author, editor, period). However you will have to ensure that you don't end up trying to show so much information in your pivot pages at once that your performance starts to suffer.

Another control you probably want to look at for this kind of app is the LongListSelector from the Silverlight Toolkit [(link here)](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). This control is similar to the one used on the People  Hub  of the phone.

Comment: Also consider looking at the new HubTile for the August (Mango) release.